# Delegating work from Spring MVC to Worker application; is Spring integration the industry standard

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration, stripe-payments, synchronous

I have a Spring MVC application which currently has a @Service injected that runs a "heavy" load, basically creating a PDF from given information. I was thinking about offloading this into a separate application, to lighten the load on the front-facing webserver.

The entire user workflow is that the user gives some information in a form, depending on the information given, he's led to one of two different forms, which enable to give more information and also payment (using Stripe). After the user sends this form, a PDF should be generated and sent to the user using email. The PDF creation is the heaviest step. In case the generating or mailing goes wrong, the Stripe payment is refunded. So all of this relies on synchronous calls.

Is Spring integration a good solution for this? I basically want my front-facing MVC server to only reply when the creation is done, because it will have the responsibility to send an email to the users and otherwise refund payment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's a good fit. You just need to choose the technology for communication to the back-end (rabbitmq, REST, JMS, or even simple RMI). The RPC is implemented by the appropriate outbound gateway and the web thread will be suspended there until the reply is received (or a timeout occurs). On the back-end, the equivalent inbound gateway is used.

One benefit is you can change the communication technology later if you decide to, with no impact on the application (either side), except for reconfiguring the gateways.